# Undefined variable: people (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laraver!I'm trying to learn some new things..
I can't find where I'm wrong, can you help me?

ContactController
[image]

Contact.blade.php

[image]

Comment: Have you tried isset() function? like `if(isset($people))`

Comment: i just tried and now there is no error, but it doesn't show anything of the array. what does this mean about my variable? it isn't set?
(btw i'm using laravel 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation on [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) and what it does.

Instead of using `compact`, change your controller's return to the following:

```
return view('contact', ['people'=>$people]);
```

Comment: thank you for the documentation!
I'm still getting the same error.
Undefined variable: people (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\contact.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
return view('contact')->with('people', $people);
return view('contact')->withPeople($people);
return view('contact')->with(compact('people');
return view('contact', ['people'=>$people]);
```

Comment: May $people[0] in blade.